How can a military exercise on the Black Sea happen with a closed Bosporus?
Romania holds a NATO naval military exercise on the Black Sea.
However, exactly the same war made also Turkey to close the Bosporus before military ships.
How can this exercise then happen? Afaik there is no way to enter the Black Sea today with large military ships.
Some important geographic, legal and logistical details for the future readers:

Bosporus is a strait between the Black Sea and the Middle Sea. It is in Turkey, close to Istambul. International law allows for Turkey to close the Bosporus on security reason; and they did it after the breakout of the 2022 Ukraine-Russia raw, before military ships (all military ships, also Russian, Ukrainian and NATO ships as well).
While Romania borders the Black Sea, not even Romanian military ships can go over the Bosporus. Thus, the Romanian fleet being in the Black Sea at the moment of the lockdown, only that qualify, and it would be hard to call as an all-NATO exercise.
A battleship is huge. You can not just pack it into trains and travel with it to the Romanian seacoast. That you can do maybe with coast guard boats, but not with battleships.
Only alternative option would be a Danube-Rhain-Main Channel, but also that is very narrow, it is clearly too narrow for a battleship.


Are you aware that Romania borders the Black Sea, and therefore doesn't need to go through the Bosphorus?

@F1Krazy While the only sea Romania borders might be the black sea that doesn't apply to all the countries that are taking part in the exercise and it is unlikely that those countries are not brining their own ships. Other countries include Bulgaria, France, Georgia, Greece, Italy, Great Britain, Moldova, the Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Turkey, and the US.

I am saying that getting ships into the black sea might not be a problem for Romania as it only borders the black sea that isn't the case for the countries that are taking part that don't border the black sea.

@F1Krazy I can only hope that it is not an answer because it would be a NAA.

@JoeW That is only the Romanian ships being on the Black Sea at the moment of the Bosporus closedown. That hardly qualifies as a NATO naval military exercise.

@JoeW A ship is BIG. You can not just pack it into trains with cranes. The only other option would be a Danube-Rhein-Main Channel, but also that hardly qualifies for battleships. It is very narrow.

Just because there are only ships from one country doesn't mean it isn't an NATO exercise if troops from multiple nations are taking part.

There are no more battleships in service in any navy.

@JoeW: and aircraft (from more than one country).

The Rhine–Main–Danube Canal is closed for traffic during April due to maintenace works at the locks. (BTW, usable max sizes for boats would be 2.1m draft, 11.4m beam and 110m length. This says minimum height under bridges might be as low as 5.25m for the relevant class Vb.)

They are probably using boats from Romania, Bulgaria, Turkey and Georgia.
There are a couple of errors in your assumptions.

Turkey has closed the Bosphorus to warships of the belligerents, except for those ships returning to their base in the Black Sea.  So Russia is unable to move warships that are based in St Petersburg or the Pacific to the Black Sea.  However, ships that are from Sevastopol are being allowed to return there. Turkey has also blocked ships from the UK that are on loan to Ukraine.

Turkey has therefore not blocked ships from Romania from passing through the straits. It has also (obviously) not blocked Turkish boats from passing through the straits.

It has also not blocked military boats that are entering the Black Sea for reasons unrelated to the Ukraine/Russia war. In particular it would allow passage for military boats from NATO countries to engage in military exercises.

Turkey is allowed, by treaty, to be the judge of which boats are allowed and which are blocked. They don't have to block all or any warships, they are allowed to exercise discretion and choose which ships may pass, according to their own perceived interest.

The particular exercises involve preparation "for missions to combat illegal activities at sea and river, maritime and river control, search and rescue at sea, assist a vessel in distress, and ensure critical infrastructure security."  These are not "battleship" duties.  In total 27 "river and maritime" vessels are involved.  This seems likely not to include the large military ships, but smaller "coast guard" type boats, probably all from Romania, but perhaps also some from Turkey, Bulgaria and Georgia, and perhaps Greece (having been permitted to enter the Black Sea through the Bosphorus.



It seems that international naval presence from countries not bordering the Black Sea is actually reduced this year (and probably since 2022). [And even that of Turkey itself.] For example, in the same annual exercise in 2021, the US sent

The Ticonderoga-class guided-missile cruiser USS Monterey (CG 61) and Arleigh Burke-class guided-missile destroyer USS Thomas Hudner (DDG 116).

But I'm not seeing a similar announcement from the US in subsequent years, i.e. since the Russian full-scale invasion of Ukraine began.  So the "27 maritime and river vessels" from this year's exercise are probably not as big & diverse as that figure makes it sound. I did find a breakdown of the ships participating in the 2023 exercise:

More than 30 military ships of the Romanian Naval Forces, two military vessels of the Bulgarian Naval Forces, and 14 aircraft from France, Romania, the United States of America and Turkey will be present at Sea Shield. They will be joined by fast intervention boats and patrol vessels, military vehicles and other combat capabilities, such as mobile launchers, detachments of special operations forces and anti-explosive and incursion combat divers, CBRN (Chemical, Biological, Radiological and Nuclear) defense specialists, and infantry and paratrooper platoons.

So that was mostly Romanian and a couple of Bulgarian ships. The rest of NATO participated with aircraft etc.
Whether this is because Turkey objects to larger NATO vessels transiting the Bosphorus, or some NATO countries feel it too risky to send their bigger naval assets to the Black Sea presently, I'm not sure.
The lack of US warships participation in Black Sea exercises after Feb 2022 was not publicly explained much, but one of the earlier events where this change happened and the press noticed was Sea Breeze 2022.

The July 2021 iteration, hosted by the U.S. and Ukraine, involved 32 warships, including the USS Ross Arleigh Burke-class guided-missile destroyer, from NATO and partners. [...]
[In 2022,] Captain Tamara Lawrence, of U.S. Naval Forces Europe-Africa, said a smaller NATO operation involving no U.S. warships was underway instead. [...]
Breeze 2022 kicked off last week, taking place away from the Russia-Ukraine fighting near Bulgarian Black Sea port cities of Varna and Burgas.
The drills will include 24 vessels, five planes, and two helicopters, according to the Bulgarian News Agency. Breeze 2022 is the first large-scale NATO exercise since Russia's latest invasion of Ukraine began.
No U.S. ships will be involved; though U.S. personnel and aircraft will.

It is noteworthy though that while Turkey is in NATO and borders the Black Sea, it didn't participate with ships in that exercise, at least in 2023, when I could find a breakdown. But it did participate with "the Turkish frigate TCG KEMALREİS" in 2021. Like with the case of US ships though, I could not find announcements that Turkish ships participated in 2022 and subsequent years. (Also, 2021 was not special, SNMG2, which typically includes one Turkish vessel, participated in other Black Sea exercises in the years prior, e.g. 2020, 2019, 2018, 2016, 2015, 2013  etc.)
I do not know how complete this tracker is, but it looks like in 2023 only Romanian and Bulgarian [foreign] military ships passed through the Bosphorus.



Note that that tracker doesn't list Turkish ships, by design. (Turkey has definitely been moving its own large warships through the straights, recently.) If you wonder what something like MAI-1107 is, it's some kind of [Romanian] coast guard vessel. The bigger ships should be easier to google. It looks like "Regele Ferdinand" took part in the Operation IRINI in the Mediterranean in June '23, and "Regina Maria" took part in Sea Guardian, in October '23, also in the Mediterranean. The situation looks similar in 2024 and in late 2022, although that year was more busy early on with Russian ships passing en mass in early February etc. So, no, the Bosphorus is not closed to Romanian warships, as you assert in your question. (More obscurely, the Romanian coast guard vessels are listed because they took part in various Frontex deployments.)
Finally, note that Turkey has been apparently pretty strict in their interpretation of the convention, in some regards. They e.g. denied passage to two demining vessels donated by the UK to Ukraine, in early 2024.

Jan 2, 2024
The Turkish government said Tuesday that it will not allow the UK to move two ex-Royal Navy minehunters through the Bosporus for delivery to Ukraine. Turkey controls the strategic waterway under the terms of the Montreux Convention of 1936. [...]
"Türkiye immediately classified Russia's special military operation against Ukraine as 'war' and, in accordance with Article 19 of the Montreux Convention . . . closed the Straits to warships of the belligerent parties (Russia and Ukraine)," the office of Turkish President Recep Tayyip Erdogan said in a statement. "Our pertinent allies have been duly apprised that the mine-hunting ships donated to Ukraine by the United Kingdom will not be allowed to pass through the Turkish Straits to the Black Sea as long as the war continues."

TBH that tracker is probably incomplete because one such minehunter bought by Romania apparently passed in late Dec 2023 but is not listed there.

BTW, and interesting analysis conducted in Jan 2022 showed that US naval presence in the Black Sea was trending downwards since 2014, in fact.
